# "no basic auth credentials" when trying to pull an image from a private ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, aws-ecr

I have the following line somewhere in the middle of my Dockerfile to retrieve an image from my private ECR.

```
FROM **********.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod/*************:ff03401
```

This is the error that I get in AWS Codebuild when trying to build this:

> Step 21/36 : FROM **********.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod/*************:ff03401 
>   Get https://**********.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/prod/*************/manifests/ff03401: no basic auth credentials

How can one provide these credentials in the most secure way, and in a way that can also be `terraform`ed?

Comment: its crazy that `docker pull <ID>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-base-image:1.0.0` works but same thing in `Dockerfile` with `FROM <ID>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-base-image:1.0.0` does not

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it.

Using aws access and secret key. In which you set the aws credentials on the ec2 machine and run ecr login command. `aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --registry-ids <some-id> --region eu-west-1` and then docker pull should work. But this is not a recommended secure way.

What I prefer is using aws [iam roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html).

Assuming you want to pull this image on your ec2 machine that was brought up using terraform. Make use of iam roles.

- Create an iam role manually or using terraform [iam resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_role.html).
- For contents of iam policy refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ecr_managed_policies.html).
- While bringing ec2 using terraform [instance resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html) make use of [iam_instance_profile](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#iam_instance_profile) attribute, the value of this attribute should be the name of iam role you created.

This should be enough to automatically pull docker images from ECR in a secure way.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the easy way first (aws ecr get-login) but still failed, posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56973938/build-a-docker-image-on-aws-codebuild-based-on-an-image-pulled-from-an-ecr-of-an