# Build a docker image on AWS Codebuild based on an image pulled from an ECR of another user: "no basic auth credentials"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-codebuild, aws-ecr

I have a line in my Dockerfile like this:

> FROM 6*********.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/*************:ff03401

This ECR is owned by another user.

As recommended [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56967033/no-basic-auth-credentials-when-trying-to-pull-an-image-from-a-private-ecr), I am trying to log in by using these commands in the `build` section of my `buildspec.yml`, and then immediately pull this docker image:

```
- aws configure set aws_access_key_id $ECR_ACCESS_KEY
- aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $ECR_SECRET_KEY
- eval aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region ap-southeast-1 --registry-ids 6***********
- docker pull 6***********.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/****************:ff03401
```

When I look at the Codebuild logs, I see that `eval aws ecr get-login...` outputs a `docker login ...` command which, if I run it on my local machine, logs me in successfully, and lets me do the `docker pull 6******...`.

In Codebuild, however, `docker pull` says:

> Error response from daemon: Get https://6**********.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/v2/******************/manifests/ff03401: no basic auth credentials

I have also tried adding `--profile ecrproduction` to the first three commands, without success.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34689445/cant-push-image-to-amazon-ecr-fails-with-no-basic-auth-credentials
Try to run ecr login inside `$()`. Let me know.

Comment: It does not work because apparently the `sh` does not support it. That's why I had to change it to `eval`.