# docker pull no basic auth credentials

Tags: docker

I was trying to use docker pull other AWS ec2 instance but got the error below.

```
(py36) ubuntu@ip-xxx:~$ docker pull xxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/xxxx/xxxx:latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://xxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/v2/xxxx/xxxx/xxx/xxxx: no basic auth credentials
```

I was referring this (https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-push-to-ecr-failing-with-no-basic-auth-credentials/17358). But it didn't work, does anyone know how to do with it?

```
~/.docker/config.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
--registry-ids <some-id>
```

Based on ["no basic auth credentials" when trying to pull an image from a private ECR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56967033/no-basic-auth-credentials-when-trying-to-pull-an-image-from-a-private-ecr/56967315)